# Weird hover selection setting in IntelliJ IDEA - how do I turn it off?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

[GIF VIDEO OF PROBLEM](https://i.imgur.com/T8iPjU8.gifv)

See the gif above for better illustrating.
Whenever I left-click, it starts to select wherever I currently hover with my mouse. I don't know why this happens, restarting IDEA does not work. It makes working very frustrating. Maybe it is some kind of setting?

Comment: Maybe your mouse button is getting stuck? Has this behavior been like that from the start or what caused it to change?

Comment: My mouse is working fine in other applications. In the start everything was normal but now suddenly today I was greeted with this. I have no idea what could've caused it, maybe something hit my keyboard and initialized a shortcut for this function.

Comment: @Markus do you have a touch screen? Does it help if you disable it? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rapidsvn/+bug/402892. Did you install any third-party plug-ins for IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Wow very interesting, I indeed do have a touch screen and I made a tap on it and suddenly everything works correctly again. How do I make your comment the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [an open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184110) related to touchscreen support (originally [reported in the forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000577850-Intellij-IDE-caret-following-cursor)). It affects all Java Swing applications (NetBeans, JEdit, etc).

To workaround the problem you can tap the screen again. This should disable the selection mode.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been restarting my laptop when ever it comes